# How to reinstall the default graphics drivers in terminal and without internet

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I accidently remove the graphics driver (I did something like `apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` and other things, I don't really remember) and now my computer boot to a console login page.

Now without GUI I cannot connect to wireless internet and so cannot install anything.

Can I revert to the initial graphics driver (and configuration)? Maybe with an installation CD? I have Ubuntu 13.10.

I tried `sudo-apt-get install --reinstall fglrx`, it did install, but when I tried `fglrxinfo`, it gives

```
Error: unable to open display (null)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initial graphics driver is the open source xorg drivers included by default. Boot into recovery mode, then select to drop to a root shell. Execute `mount -o remount,rw /` then make sure you've fully removed fglrx with `apt-get purge fglrx -y` and `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then reboot.

If you want to learn how to get access to wifi from a command line instead of a GUI, reference the following website: http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/14/connect-to-a-wireless-network-via-command-line/

Comment: Quick and excellent answer! :D Thanks a lot, mmstick!